# 301 redirect match url not working for a folder name with &

Tags: c#, url-rewrite-module

With the following `web.config` configuration, I get an error 500 (internal server error).

When I replaced the match url from `product&Services` to `ProductServices`, then no error.

```
<rule name="redirectrule18" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Product&Services/contactus" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="contact-us" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: `&` has a special meaning in XML documents. If you want to use a literal `&`, you have to escape it as `&amp;`.